# Fill N/As per ID in data set

Tags: r, na

My data set in R looks like the one below, where I have multiple IDs and Years but not always the information for Street, State, and Country.

```
ID   Year   Street        State   Country
1    2000   123 Main St   CA      USA
1    2001   N/A           N/A     N/A     
1    2002   N/A           N/A     N/A
...
1    2017   N/A           N/A     N/A
2    2001   123 Bloom Rd  CA      USA
2    2002   123 Bloom Rd  CA      USA
2    2003   N/A           N/A     N/A
...
2    2017   N/A           N/A     N/A
...
```

My goal is to fill out the N/As with the appropriate values i.e. the corresponding values per each ID. So for ID "1" there should be "123 Main Street" under the Street N/As and so on.

Thank you!

Comment: Try `library(dplyr); df1 %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate_at(vars('Street', 'State', 'Country'), funs(.[.!= 'N/A'][1]))`

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, it only worked for some observations but not for the whole data set.

Comment: it could be, that you import NA sometimes as string and sometimes a logical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the solution with both data.tbale and dplyr

```
df <- read.table(text = "ID,   Year,   Street,        State,   Country
1,    2000,   123 Main St,   CA,      USA
1,    2001,   N/A,           N/A,     N/A     
1,    2002,   N/A,           N/A,     N/A
1,    2017,   N/A,           N/A,     N/A
2,   2001,   123 Bloom Rd,  CA,      USA
2,   2002,   123 Bloom Rd,  CA,      USA
2,    2003,   N/A,           N/A,     N/A
2,    2017,   N/A,           N/A,     N/A",header = T,sep = ",")

library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars('Street', 'State', 'Country'), funs(.[!is.na(.)][1]))

library(data.table)
df <- setDT(df)
coltochange <- c("Street", "State", "Country")
df[, c(coltochange) := lapply(.SD,function(x){x[!is.na(x)][1]}),.SDcols = coltochange ,by = ID]
```

You can consider the na.locf function from zoo:

```
library(zoo)
na.locf(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `tidyverse` approach:

```
df <- read_table("ID Year Street State Country #importing the data
1 2000 123_Main_St CA USA
1 2001 N/A N/A N/A     
1 2002 N/A N/A N/A
1 2017 N/A N/A N/A
2 2001 123_Bloom_Rd CA USA
2 2002 123_Bloom_Rd CA USA
2 2003 N/A N/A N/A
2 2017 N/A N/A N/A") %>% 
  separate("ID Year Street State Country", c("ID", "Year", "Street", "State", "Country"), sep = " ") %>% # cleaning the columns
  group_by(ID) %>% # grouping by vars with same ID(Information)
  mutate_at(vars('Street', 'State', 'Country'), funs(.[.!= "N/A"][1])) # replace NA with information of same ID without NA (remember NA is still a string from import)
```